# Provide option to save job offers on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

There should be an option to save job offers on Stack Overflow.

Usually, I use Stack Overflow at my work place. If I see any interesting job here, then most of the time it is not possible for me to apply for that job at that time.

So, there should be an option to save it, so that I can apply for that job later on.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can save jobs by using our "favorite" icon. You click on the star, and then the job gets added to your favorites list for you to apply later.

[image: favorite]

Comment: Yes but is there a way to favorite from the job advertisement sidebar? I think that would be a very useful feature.

Comment: Nope, there's not. And that sounds like a useful feature. Feel free to create a new question with [meta-tag:feature-request] and make a case for it :)

Comment: Done! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369161/provide-option-to-save-job-offers-on-stack-overflow-advertisement-sidebar