# Provide option to save job offers on Stack Overflow advertisement sidebar

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360838/provide-option-to-save-job-offers-on-stack-overflow) feature is useful!

Let's add it to the advertisement sidebar as well. The star UI could appear alongside the X when the mouse hovers over the ad.

[image]

Comment: Click the job then favorite it?

Comment: Hm. That works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We actually implemented this feature a while back, as an experiment. You could favorite a job directly from the job ads. But it turned out this feature had very low usage, so we didn't graduate the experiment.

As JonH mentioned in his comment, you can click the job and then favorite it. It's just one click away!